# Symfony app on subdomain error 500

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony

I created website based on Symfony3 which is running fine on localhost. Now the project is finnished and needs to be deployed on production server's subdomain and I get the 500 error when I try to access it. No URL works, even web/config.php shows error 500.

The project is located on subdomain like this: www.subdomain.domain.cz/web

Do I need to configure something to be able to run project on subdomain? I don't have access to apache.

i tried to create simple php file with echo("hello world"); located in subdomain's root and it worked fine.

I cleared the cache before deploying.

Comment: Check your error logs

Comment: add phpinfo() to that simple php file and check if php version is >= 5.5.9

Comment: There is nothing in symfony logs and I can't access apache logs.

Comment: you also need ctype and json modules

Comment: @MichailStrokin I did that and it shows that there is php 5.6.16 version installed.

Comment: You need to be able to access server logs to do the task required. Ask whoever you need to, to give you access

Comment: How did you set up the database etc without access to the server? Even if it via a control panel, all popular ones give you access to error logs

Comment: add following snippet to the top of the web/config.php to catch all errors: https://gist.github.com/mstrokin/3c4a1a4b3c82584bbc44 (Make sure you add it after <?php )

Comment: if that doesnt produce any results, check your .htaccess file, probably Apache is doing something weird?

Comment: @MichailStrokin It produced same 500 error. I am begginer in terms of web development and don't quite understand how .htaccess works.

Comment: try to rename .htaccess to _htaccess to see if it helps. Also, did you setup your database & database configs correctly?

Comment: I contacted provider support and they said that there is missing index file so I guess the problem is in .htaccess like you guys suggested.

Comment: @MichailStrokin I did not setup it yet. I renamed .htaccess in web folder and it threw 403 error

Comment: could you paste your .htaccess here? Also, probably the error is about not having proper database configured?

Comment: .htaccess: http://pastebin.com/1KEVvucy I will set up database now.

Comment: I did set up the database and it did not help, same 500 error.

Comment: feel free to send me an email to mstrokin@gmail.com and I'll help you out when I have spare time :)

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the issue, it was in file web/.htaccess, with this:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
```

If I remove this part, it works.